# Regex, email validation taking user input from textbox

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, email

I am just trying to validate a users input using a textbox, the validation works i think. However, it is only allowing me to type one character at a time. I'm not sure how to check one char at a time until they have entered a full email address.

I think this is checking every-time when a char is entered which will result in failure until it is copy and pasted in.

```
        string strRegex = @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
            @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$";

        Regex re = new Regex(strRegex);
        if (re.IsMatch(txtEmail.Text) || txtEmail.Text == "" || txtEmail.Text.Length > 100 && txtEmail.Text.Length < 10)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Thanks");

        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email address");



        }

    }
```

Comment: I preferred to use `MailAddress` for username & domain name instead: `var email = new MailAddress(string_to_check)`, but you may want to add TLD check too as well (use specific regex for TLD).

Comment: thanks but how would i implement this to my own function ?

Comment: I think you can implement it after checking the TLD part using regex, which passes the valid string as argument to `MailAddress` instance in `try` block. If it's invalid email, use `catch` block to throw invalid email message with `MessageBox.Show`.

Comment: so is that after the validation is the if statement ? or before ?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are validating on keyup, keydown event. Validate on change event.

If you are doing in winform application you can do that on focusleave event

Answer (score 0):

@Tetsuya Yamamoto this is what i have so far, but im not sure if this is what you mean

```
        string strRegex = @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
        @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$";

        Regex re = new Regex(strRegex);
        if (re.IsMatch(txtEmail.Text) || txtEmail.Text == "" || txtEmail.Text.Length > 100 && txtEmail.Text.Length < 10)
        {
            try
            {
                var email = new MailAddress(strRegex);
                MessageBox.Show("Thanks");
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong");


            }
```